# Multiple labels for enumerated item

Tags: cross-referencing

In an enumerate-environment, I have merged two previously separate items being too similar in content. In my text, I refer to both, i.e. with two different labels. Now that they are merged this is a problem: Is there some way I can give this item two labels?

Before:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla \label{first} 
\item blu blu \label{second}
\item something
\item some other thing
\end{enumerate}
```

Wanted result:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla blu \label{first} \label{second}
\item something
\item some other thing
\end{enumerate}
```

(But the above does not work)

Comment: In my humble opinion, it is best to change the `\ref` (and this seems to me a sensible thing to do) and this is straightforward with any good editor.

Comment: I don't see any problem in giving two `\label` commands for the same object. If I do `\ref{first}` and `\ref{second}` with your "non working" input, I get "1" in both cases.

Comment: The first suggestion is not straightforward, since I am using text as input from several files.

Comment: When I include both as `\label{first} \label{second}`, only the last one will work, giving me ?? and 1, when `\ref{first}` and `\ref{second}`

Comment: I caved and followed kan's humble opinion...

Comment: If it isn't working for you, maybe you should see what other packages, macros, or other code you are using which might be interfering with it.

Comment: It may be due to the fact that I'm using the `\enumerate` package.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of reference, there is no particular reason why you couldn't use multiple labels for an item label.

**Minimal Working Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=45mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla blu \label{first} \label{second}
\item something
\item some other thing
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
Item~\ref{first} is the same as item~\ref{second} (as indeed it should be!).

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Document with duplicate labels]